# SharePoint list calculated column to sum values from another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a calculated columns in a SP list to show a running total of data from other columns.  I am doing this in excel and it works exactly as I need it to, but I cannot find anything on how to set this up in SP.  Here is an example of the excel sheet.

[image: excel sheet]

The Submitted and Fail data is summed in columns H and I as a running total.  This is what I cannot duplicate in the SP list.  The rest of the columns I was able to create and work as expected.  Columns H and I are a necessary requirement.  As I add the information into column F and G, I drag the formulas in the other columns down to the next row and everything calculates.

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Below are the limitations for SharePoint calculate columns:

- You cannot reference a value in a row other than the current row.
- You cannot reference a value in another list or library.

**Source**: [Introduction to SharePoint formulas and functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-sharepoint-formulas-and-functions-94e1b4cc-cd1c-49c2-80ec-90c9b9591f47)

---

If you want to show the SUM of column values for all rows, you can use **Sum** option in **Totals** section in view settings in number columns like:

[image]